# Don't update the "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" only for a specific action

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I've created an `update_date` column where I automatically store, for every single row, the date of when I update the rows of my table (every row is like an article page). I've done this using the `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

The problem is that I've created also a `pageview` column where I store all the visits that users do to every single page.

What I would like to is to not automatically update the `update_date` when a new visit is accounted in the `pageview` column. Is there a possibility to obtain this writing some PHP code or just using a MySQL query?

Comment: Yes, but the question is...how? :)

Comment: *"Is there a possibility ..."* is not asking how and asking how is far too broad.

Comment: I suggest you to records visits in a distinct table, linked to the articles by a foreign key, the article timestamp will update only when the article will be updated, not its page views count.

Comment: *Hm....* `affected_rows()` "might" be of use here. I'm thinking outloud, of course.

Comment: I personally don't know how, but thought this to be a good question.

Comment: I like Veve's suggestion. It has the added benefit of allowing you to see what each user is interested in instead of just which articles are most popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the timestamp field to its value, it won't be set to the current timestamp, so you can simply add `update_date = update_date` to your query:

```
UPDATE articles SET update_date = update_date, pageviews = pageviews + 1 WHERE id = :the_id;
```

But since you're actually updating your article, the `update_date` loose a little bit of its meaning.
I suggest you to records visits in a distinct table, linked to the articles by a foreign key, so the article timestamp will be updated only when the article content is really updated, not just its page views count:

For example, it can be a table <kbd>visits</kbd>, where here the article id #1 has 13 views, and the article #3 has 7. The article #2, not present, has no view:

```
+--+----------+--------+
|id|article_id|pageview|
+--+----------+--------+
| 1|        1 |     13 |
+--+----------+--------+
| 2|        3 |      7 |
+--+----------+--------+
```

Then to retrieve the pageview count for article #3:

```
SELECT pageview FROM visits WHERE article_id = 3;
```

This dissociation also has the benefit of being a perfect place to store additional informations along the number of visits, by storing one row by visit with the querystring, the User Agent and if the visitor is logged its user_id for example:

<kbd>complete_visits</kbd>

```
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
|id|article_id|querystring                  |UA     |user_id|visit_date         |
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 1|        1 |     /article/1/?search=test |Firefox|null   |2012-12-12 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 2|        1 |               /article/1/   |Firefox|12     |2012-12-13 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 3|        1 |     /article/1/?search=a    |Firefox|null   |2012-12-14 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 4|        1 |     /article/1/?search=b    |Firefox|null   |2012-12-15 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 5|        1 |     /article/1/?search=c    |Firefox|null   |2012-12-16 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 6|        1 |     /article/1/?order=asc   |IE     |null   |2012-12-17 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 7|        3 |                 /article/3/ |Chrome |null   |2012-12-18 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 8|        3 |                 /article/3/ |Firefox|4      |2012-12-19 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
| 9|        3 |     /article/3/?search=test |Firefox|null   |2012-12-20 12:12:12|
+--+----------+-----------------------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
```

To retrieve the pageview count for article #3:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM complete_visits WHERE article_id = 3;
```

Comment: I suggest you place this as a comment.

Comment: This could be a solution, I've only to understand how to link the two tables using the foreign key.

Comment: Perfect! I've done it as you suggested and it works like a charm. I decided to use the seo_url part of my url (domain.com/article-title-that-is-unique) as the one that allows me to increase the counter. So, when I add a new article, automatically I insert the seo_url also in the "visits" table and when someone accesses the article with the specific seo_url the counter automatically increase. In this way my main article table timestamp is not affected by this update. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Either you change your table, so you don't autoupdate the `update_date`, but explicitly only set the `update_date` to `now()` when you update the contents, or, `update contents set counter=counter+1,update_date=update_date where id=12345;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand...can I ask you to please explain it? I've no now() in my MySQL attibute.

Comment: now() is a mysql function returning the current timestamp. Try "select now()"

Comment: Solved using the Veve solution. Thanks anyway for your kind support.